# Lagged difference between rows in R_ a different take

Tags: r, dplyr, diff, lag, difference

My question is similar to a few that have been asked before, but I hope different enough to warrant a separate question.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080716/find-difference-between-two-rows-using-dplyr-suppresswarnings-leads-to-na-for), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776233/lagged-differences). I'll pull some of the same example data as these questions. For context to my question- I am looking to see how my observed catch-rate (sea creatures) changed over multiple days of sampling the same area.

I want to calculate the difference between the first sample day at a given site (first Letter in data below), and the subsequent sample days (next rows of same letter).

```
 #Example data   
 df <- data.frame(
 id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
 num = c(1, 8, 6, 3, 7, 7 , 9),
 What_I_Want = c(NA, 7, 5, 2, NA, 0, 2))
```

The first solution that I found calculates a lagged difference between each row. I also wanted this calculation- so it was helpful to find:

```
#Calculate lagged differences
df_new <- df %>% 
# group by condition
group_by(id) %>% 
# find difference
mutate(diff = num - lag(num))
```

Here the difference is between A.1 and A.2; then A.2 and A.3 etc...

What I would like to do now is calculate the difference with respect to the first value of each group. So for letter A, I would like to calculate 1 - 8, then 1 - 6, and finally 1 - 3. Any suggestions?

One clunky solution (linked above) is to create two (or more) columns for each distance lagged and some how merge the results that I want

```
df_clunky = df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(
deltaLag1 = num - lag(num, 1),
deltaLag2 = num - lag(num, 2))
```

Comment: note: 1 - 8 is -7, rather than 7

Comment: @Hack-R yes thank you, I've been using abs() on my real data and thinking in terms of absolute difference, but you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method with `replace` and `ave`

```
ave(df$num , df$id, FUN=function(x) replace(x - x[1], 1, NA))
[1] NA  7  5  2 NA  0  2
```

`ave` applies the `replace` function to each id. `replace` takes the difference of the vector and the first element in the vector as its input and replaces NA into the first element.